# How do i make a quiz top-5 wrong answers?

Tags: php, sql

I've been making a quiz, and the core of the quiz is done... What I need now is this:

I got a user registration and in my quiz, when a user has answered correctly on a question, he should be able to see how many people answered wrong to that question.

So far I've been able to check all the correct answers the user has made by joining the 'answers' table with the 'question' table... And checking it that way...

What I would like to be able to know is top-5 of the wrong answers on a question... I got a the table called 'answers' and I know the question_id in it... So how do I find the wrongs answers and then find out which of those has been answered most times?

```
SELECT * FROM answers

WHERE question_id = 1

AND answer IN (

SELECT answer 

FROM answers

GROUP BY answer

HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
)
```

This query selects the values that there are most of in the table.

My problems are that i need to know the number of each different values inserted (and then order by the highest number). Say the users in my database answered 'Cake and bacon' 123 times then there would be 123 answers in the database with that value... But i dont want all the rows with that value, i want 1 row with the value 123.

And because i want to make a top-5 of wrong answers, i want it to leave out the correct answers.

Sorry this is very confusing to explain. Hope you understand, and thanks for reading!

Best regards,
Mathias

Comment: Assuming all the questions are "choose only one" and not "choose all that apply" type answers, then modify your inner query to exclude the correct answer.

Comment: Would be cool if you could show us your database layout (for these two tables). Maybe there is a totally different aproach with columns you did not mention.

Comment: Which SQL (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, etc.) are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more information about your table structure would be useful. Based on what you have provided I think you just need to do this:

```
SELECT answer, count(*) FROM answers

WHERE question_id = 1

AND answer != "<correct answer>"

Group By answer

Order By count(*) Desc;
```

This will count each answer and order them from most to least frequent.